# How to catch/throw errors with QAxObject

Tags: c++, excel, qt, try-catch, throw

I want use `QAxObject` to work with Excel files. 
I want implement initialization somehow like following code:

```
QAxObject* excel;//excel pointer

void initExcel(){
    try
    {
        //if there excel process already running try to use it
    }
    //catch if it's not running
    catch()
    {
        try 
        {
            excel = new QAxObject("Excel.Application");
        } 
        catch 
        {
            //meassge if excel not exist/can't start     
        }
    }
}
```

How could I catch/throw errors with QAxObject? I tried to google it but didn't found any exapmlpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know if ActiveX control loaded, you should use the result of setControl method. To catch ActiveX control's exceptions, you should connect to exception signal.

```
bool controlLoaded = axWidget->setControl("Word.Document");
if (!controlLoaded)
{
    // Message about control didn't load
}
else
{
    // Control loaded OK; connecting to catch exceptions from control
    connect(
        axWidget, 
        SIGNAL(exception(int, const QString &, const QString &, const QString &)), 
        this, 
        SLOT(onAxWidgetException(int, const QString &, const QString &, const QString &)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, countryman! :) I'll accept your answer later, ok? I'm afraid that today I got some other stuff, I'll check your soultion tomorrow